# Eloquent ORM; M-N relationship limit results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

I have a `Many to Many` relationship (`Category belongsMany Product` and `Product belongsMany Category`).

I want to select all categories and each category I want to get 10 products by using Eloquent.

My code:

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function($query)
{
    $query->limit(10);
}])->get();
```

It just get 10 products for all categories instead of 10 products for each category.

Comment: Have you checked out documentation yet? Are you on L4 or L5.

Comment: So, how are you loading "all" records, then we can talk about limiting... (edit question and post model). Are you waiting that SO people show you?